# Why does silverstripe set my page tables as obsolete one

Tags: php, silverstripe, obsolete

**Hello**,

I have a big problem with silverstripe. Everything was okay until i flushed my site and suddenly i got some errors with this on the dev/build :

```
Table Page: renamed to _obsolete_Page
Table Page_versions: renamed to _obsolete_Page_versions
Table Page_Live: renamed to _obsolete_Page_Live
```

So silverstripe set all my page tables as obsolete ones and my site does not work anymore!
Does anybody already had this issue?
I tried to find some explanations in the code but did not find anything...
Please help me :(

Comment: If it's just a naming issue, could you not just re-rename them? (I've no experience with silverstripe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll mark your tables as obsolete if it doesn't detect any need for them (no $db or $has_one arrays on the object). What fields should be stored on your Page database?

Comment: Okay, i figured it out. I removed the $db and the $has_one features from my page class a long time ago and i was still calling them somewhere in my code until today so my code crashed! It took me a while to understand that silverstripe set a table as obsolete when there is no $db or $has_one in the class even if it's explained in the doc...sorry.
So everything is fine now and Thank you for your answer!